# How to pull active tab first int the position and push the another after the active one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 nav tabs i need when click one and become active to be first tab and the other come after it

```js
$(".nav-tabs a").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).css('margin-right', '0px');
    $(this).css('margin-left', '-139px');
  }
});
if (!$(".nav-tabs a").hasClass('active')) {
  $(this).css('margin-right', '-139px');
  $(this).css('margin-left', '0px');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item ">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">
      <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> زيارة بالساعة</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">
      <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> زيارة بالشهر</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advise you to use more elegant solution, without direct css mutations. You can on tab click just [prepend()](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/) current tab to the parent's div and it will be first. I've prepared a [sample fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/98frz321/8/) for you.

```
$(".nav-item").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().prepend(this);
});
```

Comment: Glad to help you